# Why is JMockit throwing a NullPointerException with no stack trace?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

Edit: I noticed that this is only a problem on JMockit 1.42 and later, so I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/639)

I have something similar to the following code

```
 class Type1 {

 }

 class Type2 {
      private final Type1 TYPE_1;

      Type2(Type1 type1) {
           TYPE_1 = type1;
      }

      // A bunch of methods involving TYPE_1
 }
```

I am trying to test `Type2` with TestNG by mocking a `Type1` instance with JMockit. I have the following test.

```
 class Type2Test {
      @Tested
      Type2 type2;

      @Injectable
      Type1 type1;


      @Test
      void randomTestThatShouldPass() {
           Assert.assertTrue(true);
      }
 }
```

However, when running this test, I get a `NullPointerException` with no apparent stack trace. The following is all that shown on my console.

> java.lang.NullPointerException

I have tried a bunch of things to solve my problem including:

- Making TYPE_1 non-final
- Removing `@Injectable` from  `type1` in `Type2Test`. This gives me a better error message by telling me JMockit could not instantiate `type2` because there are no `@Injectable` instances to invoke the constructor for `Type2`
- Changed `@Injectable` to `@Mocked`
- Switching environments. The same problems occur on both VSCode and Intelij
- Using Gradle instead of Maven

The only thing that solves it is by removing all of JMockit's annotations, which is not helpful. What am I doing wrong in my test setup?

Edit: Responding to paulsm4 comment, I am not using Spring, but I am using Maven 3.5.3 with the following pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ok.ubc.cosc.VisualizeCode</groupId>
  <artifactId>VisualizeCode</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>VisualizeCode</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
       <plugins>
            <plugin>
                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>3.8.1</version>
                 <configuration>
                      <source>1.8</source>
                      <target>1.8</target>
                 </configuration>
            </plugin>
       </plugins>
 </build>
 <dependencies>
      <dependency>
           <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
           <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
           <version>6.14.3</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
           <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
           <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
           <version>1.48</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 </project>
```

Comment: It sounds like a) You're probably using Spring Boot (SB 2?), and b) Your (Maven?  Gradle?) config isn't bringing in the right libraries at the right time.  Please update your post with the relevant "dependencies" from your build file.  Also: please add your environment(e.g. "Spring Boot") to your "tags".

Comment: @paulsm4 I am not using Spring Boot, but I am using Maven. I have updated the question with my pom.xml file

Comment: OK: so how is "@Injectable" working?  I assumed you were using Spring Boot for your "DI container".  What *ARE* you using to implement DI?  I'm not saying it's "wrong" ... but I *AM* curious...

Comment: @paulsm4 [JMockit](http://javadox.com/org.jmockit/jmockit/1.12/mockit/Injectable.html) is the library corresponding to `@Injectable`. It tells JMockit that this instance can be injected into test code (I assume this is what you mean by a DI container).

Comment: OK: I think that's the problem.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26762680/421195): `The thing to notice about JMockit's (or any other mocking API) support for dependency injection is that it's meant to be used only when the code under test actually relies on the injection of its dependencies.`  This tutorial might help: https://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Introduction.html#mocks

Comment: @paulsm4 Nothing in that link helped. From what I see, the big difference between the question asker's code and the accepted answer is that they he replaced `@Injectable` with `@Mocked` which I have already tried and stated.

Comment: @paulsm4 To save you time in case you look into more, I noticed that my code (with and without the changes from the link) works with JMockit version 1.41 but none after that.

Comment: Fair enough.  I've re-opened and upvoted your question.  In case others didn't notice your edit, you've opened an "issue" against JMockit here: https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/639

Comment: Does `Type1` really not have any method?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle `Type1` does have methods in my real project (as does `Type2`). I was trying to emphasize that `Type1` has a zero-argument constructor.

Comment: Are you using aspectjweaver javaagent? It doesn't play well with JMockit.